# Remove Name Notepad file if doesnt exist in AD through powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$Users = GC "Desktop\Master.txt"

foreach ($user in $users) {

$userobj = $(try {Get-ADUser $user} catch {$Null})

If ($userobj -ne $Null) {

   Write-Host "$User Exists"

} else {

   Write-Host "$User Doesn't Exist"

}}
```

I am using this code to check if a user exists in AD. Later on this notepad file is processed to delete the users that are on the file. I was going to see if it was possible that I can remove the users off the list that don't exist. Is there a command to remove the line from the Notepad file that has the names on if the user doesn't exist in AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to test just a single user:

```
function Test-ADUser {
  param($Identity)

  try {
    $null = Get-ADUser @PSBoundParameters -ErrorAction Stop

    # user must exist if we reached this point
    return $true
  }
  catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]{
    return $false
  }
}
```

Now you can use `Where-Object` to filter the list from the text file based on what the function determines:

```
# Read list from file, filter out usernames that don't exist
$filteredList = Get-Content "Desktop\Master.txt" |Where-Object { Test-ADUser -Identity $_ }

# Write filtered data back to disk
$filteredList |Set-Content "Desktop\Master.txt" -Force
```

Comment: Does the function go inside the IF statement or does this replace what I have written entirely? Kind Regards

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr Nope, no `if` statements necessary. Just put the two blocks of code in my answer into your script as-is - that's all the code you need :) Just make sure the function is defined before you try calling it